Does it make sense to create a confidence interval referencing the Z-distribution if we know the population distribution isn't normal?
I'm taking an introductory statistics course for my biology degree and, when learning about generating the confidence interval for the population mean, I started wondering if it'd make sense to do so in the case that we knew that the original population isn't normally distributed. To my knowledge, the CLT doesn't have any utility in such a case, because what we care about is creating a confidence interval whose assumed chances agree with the original probability distribution, that of the population.
Am I missing something? If not, what would be the procedure for evaluating the correctedness of referencing such or such theoretical distribution to construct the confidence interval?
Clarification edit:
I am not asking about the CLT's effect on the sampling distribution and its estimators, but about the utility of using an asymptotically-normal sampling distribution to make inferences about population parameters, in the case that we know that the population is not at all normal. So, my question is: how can we use a normal sampling distribution to try to estimate things about a population that is not normal, when the sampling distribution will have such differently distributed probabilities, that the two distributions look nothing alike?

Please see our posts about sampling distributions.  Reviewing the context and conclusion of the CLT is also likely to be helpful.

This question is similar to: Debunking wrong CLT statement. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The population distribution is not the sampling distribution of the statistic. The approximation with a normal distribution is about the latter instead of the first. There are many questions about this.

Other related posts https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476435/

@SextusEmpiricus None of the linked questions mentions confidence intervals, so they are rather obviously different (no edit required), even though of course the issue with population vs. sampling distribution also comes up elsewhere. Similarities may be more obvious to statisticians than to somebody taking Introductory Stats for Biologists.

The issue here may just be one of not correctly understanding what a confidence interval is. It is an interval for a parameter (such as a population mean), not an interval for an observation. See the first sentence of the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

@Glen_b Yes, I think I understand what a confidence interval is: it's a region of accumulated probability bounded by the critical values of the sampling distribution which correspond to the limits of the certainty we want to approach a prediction about a population parameter with. My confusion arises from using a normally-distributed sampling variable to make inferences about a completely different distribution, when the way the cumulative probabilities are organized differs so much from one to the other.

@ChristianHennig I'd like to study biomathematics in grad school, so any extra rigour is welcomed!


To my knowledge, the CLT doesn't have any utility in such a case, because what we care about is creating a confidence interval whose assumed chances agree with the original probability distribution, that of the population. Am I missing something?

I believe you are confusing confidence intervals and prediction intervals.
To start, confidence intervals represent uncertainty in the mean.  Imagine standing somewhere prominent on campus and asking 10 people who pass you by what their grade in calculus was.  The average grade you get from these 10 people is going to vary depending on which 10 people you ask.  This variability is what the confidence interval is intended to convey.  This is all together different than predicting what the grades for those 10 people may be.
The CLT has IMMENSE utility here because the CLT gives us the distribution of the sample mean (in the limit of large samples).  The population distribution is irrelevant (well, nearly irrelevant.  It needs to have finite variance) -- so long as the observations from that population are IID, the sample mean will be normally distributed with mean equal to the population mean and variance equal to the population variance divided by the number of samples.
You can see this quite readily with some simulation.  Suppose the distribution of the true calculus grades looks like something below.  A few people get around 60, more get around 75, and a small minority get around 90.

Its quite easy to sample from this distribution with the R code below.

set.seed(0)
x <- seq(50, 100, 0.01)
weights <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)
means <- c(60, 75, 90)
sds <- c(2, 3, 1)


vrs <- sds^2
y <- 0
for(i in 1:3){
  y <- y + weights[i] * dnorm(x, means[i], sds[i])
}

plot(x, y, type='l', ylab = 'Density', xlab='Calculus Grade')


true_mean <- sum(weights*means)
true_var <- sum(weights*vrs) + sum(weights*means^2) - (sum(weights*means))^2



sample_calculus <- function(n) {
    component <- sample(1:3, size = n, prob = weights, replace = T) # Select component
    rnorm(n, mean = means[component], sd = sds[component]) # Sample from the chosen component
}



Now, I'm going to repeatedly sample 10 people from the population, get their grade, and plot the mean.  I'm going to do this 1000 times.  You will see that the means will vary, because the sample from which they are computed varies.  Here is the R code
n_samples <- 10
avg_grades <- replicate(1000, mean(sample_calculus(n_samples)))

# Plot the density of avg_grades
hist(avg_grades, probability = T)

# Add a vertical line at the mean of the simulated averages
abline(v = mean(avg_grades), col = "red", lty = 2, lwd = 2)
lines(x, dnorm(x, true_mean, sqrt(true_var/n_samples)), col='red')

As you can see, while the population distribution is definitely NOT normal (although it is a finite mixture of normals), the sampling distribution of the mean IS very close to being normal.
Now, the quality of the approximation of the true sampling distribution to a normal requires considering the sample size and the variance in the population, so I don't want you walking away thinking you can apply the CLT willy nilly.  But when the population distribution is moderately well behaved, it can be justified to think of the sampling distribution as being normal enough to be useful.


tidyverse is a massive library, and loading it can cause all sorts of issues. Glancing over your code, it doesn't actually depend on tidyverse anyway, so you'd do people a massive favour by just deleting that line.

@AkselA you’re free to edit the answer as you see fit. I load the tidyverse by habit, and I don’t think it causes “all sorts of issues”.

‘Can’ cause all sorts of issues. What you do on your own machine is your concern, but code you share here is meant to be, among other things, minimal, out of consideration for others who want to run it.


Note that we construct confidence intervals (CIs) for certain parameters of probability distributions, and we may in principle be interested in many different CIs, meaning that in principle for your question to be well defined you'd need to specify what CI you are interested in. One standard case is the mean parameter $\mu$ under the assumption that your data are ${\cal N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (normally) distributed. I'm assuming this is the case you are interested in (in reality we may well also be interested in a CI for the variance $\sigma^2$, even if normality holds).

The standard CI for $\mu$ in the normal case is based on a $z$-statistic in case that $\sigma^2$ is known and fixed, which is a situation which is sometimes taught in courses but very rarely of practical relevance. The normal distribution is also the sampling distribution of the $z$-statistic in this case, so the CI is computed based on the normal distribution.

Note however that there is a distinction between the distribution of the original data, and the sampling distribution of the $z$-statistic (which would apply to reapeated sampling of samples of the same size), which is relevant for CIs. Only in this specific case, both the distribution of the original observations and the sampling distribution are normal.

If $\sigma^2$ is unknown, the standard CI is constructed based on a $t$-statistic, the sampling distribution of which is a $t$-distribution (under normal assumption for the original data).

If the distribution generating the data is not normal (but still independently identically distributed with finite variance), the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) says that sample mean and therefore also the $z$-statistic (based on the mean) are asymptotically normal, i.e., for sample size $n$ converging to infinity. This means that if your sample is reasonably large (in most cases $n>30$ is enough, but unfortunately there are certain exceptions), the CI based on the normal distribution is still approximately valid for the underlying true population mean. I repeat that for constructing the CI, the sampling distribution of the used statistic is important, which is in general not the same as the distribution that generated the data. The CLT applies to the former, not the latter, which is good news here.

The same applies to the $t$-statistic and the CI based on it in case $\sigma^2$ is unknown (for $n\to\infty$, the $t$-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom converges to the normal distribution; another theoretical ingredient on top of the CLT is needed for this, which is Slutsky's Theorem). This means that the $z$- and $t$-CI are often valid also if your sample does not come from the normal distribution.

This is extremely useful particularly because statistical models are idealisations and nothing is ever perfectly normally distributed.



Confidence intervals do not directly care about the original population distributions. They care about the distributions of the estimators used to estimate population parameters. The catch is that these distributions of estimators do depend on the original distributions. However, beause of convergence theorems like the central limit theorem, they can be much less sensitive to the original distributions than you might expect.
For instance, let's look at the distribution of the sample mean for samples drawn from a quite skewed exponential distribution. I will simulate this in R software.
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
set.seed(2024) # Only a few more days of this seed!

Ns <- c(2, 30, 100, 1000) # Sample sizes
R <- 1000 # Number of times to run the simulation at each sample size

L <- list()

for (i in 1:length(Ns)){
  
  means <- rep(NA, R)
  
  for (j in 1:R){
    
    x <- rexp(Ns[i], 1)
    means[j] <- mean(x)
  }
  
  d_empirical <- data.frame(
    Mean = means,
    CDF = ecdf(means)(means),
    Distribution = "Empirical",
    Size = Ns[i]
  )
  d_theoretical <- data.frame(
    Mean = means,
    CDF = pnorm(means, 1, sqrt(1/Ns[i])),
    Distribution = "Theoretical",
    Size = Ns[i]
  )
  d <- rbind(d_empirical, d_theoretical)
  L[[i]] <- d
}

# Combine all of the data frames
#
d_final <- data.table::rbindlist(L)

# Plot!
#
ggplot(d_final, aes(x = Mean, y = CDF, col = Distribution)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Size), scales = "free_x") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


At a sample size of two, the empirical and theoretical distributions have an obvious disagreement. Perhaps a sample size of two is not large enough to use the approximation you learned in class. However, at even a sample size of thirty, the differences are not so visually apparent, and by the time the sample size hits 1000, I only see one curve on the plot, indicating a very strong match.
Every one of the empirical distributions differs from the theoretical normal distribution by at least a little bit, but the point is that, for even modest sample sizes like thirty, the approximation is close enough to be a useful tool that avoids issues that go along with methods like, say, bootstrap confidence intervals that are more complicated than is appropriate for an introductory course and may not even offer an improvement in simple situations.
(Make no mistake that bootstrap is useful in complicated situations, however.)


To my knowledge, the CLT doesn't have any utility in such a case,
because what we care about is creating a confidence interval whose
assumed chances agree with the original probability distribution, that
of the population. Am I missing something?

Yes. Your estimate of the population mean is based on the obtained sample mean; therefore, what really matters is the probability distribution of possible sample means, which is different from the population.
The whole point of the CLT is to describe this difference: that the distribution of possible sample means tends to normality, regardless of the population distribution. Knowing this is what allows the estimation of the population mean, from a sample, to be generally feasible.
Most textbook guidelines (check yours) will suggest that if you have a sample size of 30 or more, then the distribution of the sample mean will be approximately normal (i.e., close enough for a practical estimate), regardless of the shape of the population.
As a college instructor, I feel that this is the single most important insight in the introductory statistics course that unlocks "inferential thinking". Consider practicing with the quiz here: Automatic Algebra: Sampling Distributions.

Thank you! Unfortunately, my professor hasn't followed any textbooks, so I'm learning by blending several courses I've found online. Also, yes, I know that by the CLT the sample mean distribution will sufficiently approximate a normal distribution with n>30. Regardless, my issue is with that not being -- to my mind -- relevant in the case the population is not normally distributed. If the population is say, of a Chi-squared's distribution shape, we can't use a normal distributions to make inferences about it; their shapes are so different, and their probabilities accumulated differently.

@David: The shape of the population doesn't matter (b/c you're not pulling one thing from the population). It's the shape of the sample mean that counts (b/c you're inspecting the mean of one sample), and that's always approximately normal for any large sample size.

This is a good answer, but it's worth pointing out that the ">=30" rule of thumb and the meaning of "large" can be problematic: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898, for instance.  Perhaps this is the motivating issue for the present question?

@DanielR.Collins Yes, but I think I'm not making myself understood. My issue is with the predictive validity of the sample distribution, not with the conditions for said distribution to approach normality.

I think you said at least twice in the question that you're finding a confidence  interval for the population mean. But other things you say make it appear that you may be interested in something other than the population mean. What, for example, is the probability that a new observation will be between $\widehat\mu-\widehat\sigma$ and $\widehat\mu+\widehat\sigma\text{ ?}$ If $\widehat\mu$ and $\widehat\sigma$ are estimates of the population mean and the population standard deviation based on very large samples, and the population is normally distributed, you could say it's about $0.68.$ If it's a different distribution, that probability would probably be a very different number. But if all you want is a confidence interval for the population mean, not for the probability distribution, then CLT does it.
Estimating the probability distribution itself is another matter. You certainly cannot conclude it's normal when the data says otherwise. A huge amount of ink has been spilled on that problem.

Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. It is indeed the predictive value of the confidence interval for the population mean what I was asking about. My reasoning is that it can't be very good if the original distribution lies very far off from normality.

@David : Even if you knew the population mean EXACTLY, that wouldn't give you much information about the distribution. But that is not a valid criticism of the use of the CLT to find a confidence interval for the population mean. What you seem to be trying to estimate is something other than the population mean.

So, maybe it's just that my base on the matter is wrong in itself. But, in principle, I understand that one utilizes the sample mean distribution to make predictions about the population mean because of the knowledge that, through the CLT, said sample mean distribution will tend to be tightly packed around the most frequent value of the original distribution -- in the case such original distribution resembles, at least reasonably, normality. In the case there's no normality in the population, but a very skewed distribution, the sample mean distribution will not have

its probabilities distributed in such a manner so as to resemble the original distribution, because its values won't correspond to those truly closest to the mean of said original distribution.

What I'm talking about doesn't depend necessarily on the foreknowledge about the original distribution. As such, if one sampled a large of n in order to predict the population mean, and it turned out that the population had a very weird shape, then the sample mean wouldn't be a good estimator purely by virtue of the starking difference between the two distributions.

So, imagine, for instance, an population distributed in such a way that there are a huge lot of values close to 0, and then a few extremely large values: such that the average results in a value of about 40. The sampling would take mostly values close to 0, and maybe none of those extremely large ones; the sample mean would also be close to 0, and with no predictive value with regards to the original distribution. This is the kind of scenario that ignited my confusion and the question.

@David You seem to confuse two different things with each other: (1) estimation of the population mean, and (2) estimation of the population distribution. One thing you wrote is flatly false: "said sample mean distribution will tend to be tightly packed around the most frequent value of the original distribution". That is grossly wrong. Consider the number of "heads" you get each time you toss a coin. It's either $0$ or $1.$ But with a large number of tosses, the sample mean will be near $1/2,$ which is not one of the values of the original distribution.

BEGIN QUOTE if one sampled a large of n in order to predict the population mean, and it turned out that the population had a very weird shape, then the sample mean wouldn't be a good estimator END QUOTE  The sample mean WOULD be a good estimator of the population mean. But you could NOT get a good estimate of the population distribution, based only on the sample mean. However, if you have all of the observations in the sample, rather than just their mean, then you could get a good estimate of the population distribution. That has nothing to do with the CLT.
